# Android: Touch draw not working properly

Tags: android, android-canvas, statusbar, titlebar

I want to draw anything but using touch. I followed [this](http://androidrises.blogspot.in/2012/10/draw-line-on-finger-touch.html) tutorial. But my drawing does not start from the point I touch the screen.

I also tried including height of status-bar and title-bar but it didn't work.

**My activity code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
float downx = 0, downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    return r.top;
}

public int getTitleBarHeight() {
    int viewTop = getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT)
            .getTop();
    return (viewTop - getStatusBarHeight());
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        downx = event.getX();
        downy = event.getY() - getStatusBarHeight() - getTitleBarHeight();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        upx = event.getX();
        upy = event.getY()+ getStatusBarHeight() + getTitleBarHeight();
        canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
        imageView.invalidate();
        downx = upx;
        downy = upy;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: I guess, removing status bar and title bar would solve your problem. But thats not the appropriate solution...

Comment: The link(blogspot) you reffered also has comments that signifies your problem. I don't know whether they have found the solution.

Comment: Why are you basing the Bitmap's dimensions on the screen if you're only drawing to the ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yourcode

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

change it as shown here [link](http://androidrises.blogspot.in/2012/10/draw-line-on-finger-touch.html) and check it

```
Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: I think it would make no difference. In addition, getWidth() and getHeight() methods are deprecated.